# I am unable to switch virtualenv with virtualenvwrapper in Fabric

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, fabric, virtualenvwrapper

I am using `virtualenvwrapper` to use `virtualenv` for my Django deployement.
Following is my Fabric task:

```
proj_path = '/path/to/proj'

def setup_code():
    sudo('pip install virtualenvwrapper')
    run('export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs')
    run('source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh && mkvirtualenv myenv')
    run('source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh && workon myenv')
    cd(proj_path)
    req_file = os.path.join(proj_path, 'requirements.txt')
    run('pip install -r %s' % req_file)
```

I executed the above `fab` task, but it's behaving strangely. `pip` starts retrieving all the packages, and then starts to execute the setup file for them. While executing `setup` file it crashes saying `Permission denied`.

But why? It's working inside `~` and `virtualenv`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Figured out the problem :

For Fabric :

```
cd('dir') # doesn't works.
```

Following works:

```
with cd('dir'):
    print('pwd') # Directory change reflects here.
```

Similarly, other environmental things like :

```
run('export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs')
run('source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh && mkvirtualenv myenv')
run('source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh && workon myenv')
```

But changed to :

```
with prefix('WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs'):
    with prefix('source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh'):
        with prefix('workon myenv'): # Assuming there is a env called `myenv`
            run('pip install -r requirements.txt') # Works in virtualenv
```

Figured it out from the official documentation : http://docs.fabfile.org/en/stable/api/core/context_managers.html

Comment: Note that `source` is not known by `sh` (which Fabric uses)

Comment: How do you manage to get this working when bash is not the default shell then ?

Answer (score 0):

I think thats dont works because then you active virtualenv its do some magic with your existing environment, but as I know fabric doesnt has its own shell with environment. You can try like this:

```
 run('/home/your_folder/virtualenv/bin/pip install -r %s' % req_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use your `.bashrc`, then here's a solution that'll work with latest Fabric (1.10) + virtualenvwrapper (1.11.4):

```
with shell_env(WORKON_HOME=run('printf $HOME/.virtualenvs'),
        prefix('source /usr/share/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper.sh'):

    run('mkvirtualenv foo')    
    with prefix('workon foo'):
        run('which python')
```